# Window Security asks to connect to proxy

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy

This is a recent change.  It asks me to connect with a proxy- but in my office, we have no proxy connection.  I can not find where to change the setting anywhere.  When I try to use FireFox for an intranet site, FF also asks me a login to the proxy.

Now I notice the MS Store will not connect, and the MS News app will not connect either.  Any thoughts on where I need to go to change the setting?

[image]

Comment: You should contact your office administrator.  The required changes to fix this problem require Administrator access.

Comment: The only thing you can try is to delete your Firefox user profile, this will reset any and all configurations if Firefox then that would confirm your issue is likely malicious software.  You should still contact an Administrator even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Caveat: I'm not using Windows now, so maybe I'm giving you wrong information(also because my Windows is in Italian and I don't remember the exact English labels), but the answer is more or less this:

in "Control Panel", search for "Internet Settings", double-click on it, then search for the tab "Connections", click on it, select your LAN; in the bottom will appear a button labeled "LAN settings". Clicking on it you should see a dialog with LAN settings, and the proxy settings. The radio button must have the "No proxy" selection (or "Direct connection").

If the problem is in FF only, in the FF Preferences, click on "Advanced", then click on the "Network" tab. Click on the "Connection settings", and the page that shows must have the selection for "use system settings".

If this doesn't solve the problem, explain to us how is set your network. Also, if you open a Command Prompt, typing "ipconfig" Windows will tell you a lot of information about your network.

Comment: Thanks- Check "ipconfig" - nothing crazy there-Ipv6 & 4 Subnet/Mask adb default gateway-Lan setting- is set to auto detect- I think our "modem" need to reset but IT and they will not touch it just to try and solve my problem- I keep poking around to see what I can find.

Comment: One more weird thing- after I reboot it tells me that I have no internet connection but I do get out on a browser-
the error message- "you might need to sign up with this networks ISP to get access."  Then after about 20 minutes it connects.
And after the reboot I also get the weird chrome browser automatically starts to a MSN page-, I noticed that others have the same problem, nothing seems to stop it- It just boggle my mind how these weird things suddenly appear on a otherwise fine running machine.